# Destroy Coffee Cup (Vayikra 11:33), when fly dies in beverage?

Tags: mitzvah, kashering-kosherization, sefer-vayikra

**Considering [Vayikra 11:33](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.33?lang=bi&aliyot=0) - Should a [Restaurant] owner who sees their customer’s ceramic coffee cup ☕️ contains a dead fly, break the cup & dispose (or wash it for future customers)?**

- Question based on commentary by Chizkuni require smashing the cup? : "because there is no way to dispose of this contamination except by breaking the vessel in question" (https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.33?with=Chizkuni&lang=bi&aliyot=0).

Comment: Ritual impurity and kashruth are two different matters.

Comment: There is nothing to do with Cashrut. This is a sherets met who is av hatumea and is metame cli cheres mitocho, a unic kind of tumea without touching, moving or any other known kind of way to get tumea, existing in Clay pots only

Comment: @kouty Is a fly a sheretz

Comment: @Deuteronomy | the matter is : Should owner Wash or Destroy the coffee cup contaminated by dead flies?

Comment: @Hida that depends on the context, which you have not made clear.

Comment: @Deuteronomy | See update for context.

Comment: @DoubleAA you ask an other question. The translation of the verse

Comment: Rabenu Tam says it's natlaf the rashba also and see raah bedeq habayit regarding the flye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emphatic **NO**. Clean the cup and move on.

That verse is talking about a dead small mammal or lizard falling into a raw (unglazed) clay pot; the clay pot is now ritually impure and can't be made ritually pure.

Guess what? Today we are all ritually impure! As we're not bringing sacrifices in the Temple, it pretty much doesn't matter.

Furthermore, that was talking about something the size of a mole or lizard, not a fly.

The separate question is whether the food is **kosher**. The good news here is that Shulchan Aruch rules that bugs are basically tasteless, so we don't worry about minute quantities of "bug juice" in our food. (The Talmud actually says if a fly lands in your soup, a normal person removes the fly and carries on.)

Comment: Doesn’t Gittin 90.b:17 associate negative behavior with eating accidental ‘fly-soup’?

Comment: Yes -- that's saying don't try to do so (its example of the uncouth fellow). But the normal behavior -- "just pull the fly out of the soup" in fact implies that if a minute amount of bug juice winds up in your food, you ignore it and move on.

Comment: So based on Gittin If you replace the non-kosher fly (with 1 bacon bit) in soup, consuming the 1 minute amount of pork fat would be fine (as long as you pull bacon bit out of the soup)?

Comment: NO NO NO!!!!!! The point is that **BUGS** ARE TASTELESS and therefore minute amounts (even more than 1:60) are not a problem. Pork fat imparts flavor, and therefore you need to "nullify" it 60x by volume ... and if it's fat why aren't you just cooling it to congeal it ... it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Bugs aren't **tasteless**, their taste is **foul**

Comment: @robev thank you, fair enough.